# . /etc/default/unicorn not found digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, unicorn

I use Ubuntu 16.04 for rails deployment. It have puma web server by default by I am using unicorn in my app.

For unicorn settings when I run command

```
. /etc/default/unicorn
```

It not found.

Answer (score 5):

I asked this and Digital Ocean support said:

> The instructions should be updated as the location oft hat [sic] file has
>   changed on Ubuntu 16.04, due to the usage of systemd on that version
>   of Ubuntu.
>
> You can find the file here: /etc/systemd/system/unicorn.service

Comment: you deploy rails 5 on digitalocean 16.04?

Comment: I actually deployed the Rails 5 app I was working on to a Digital Ocean CentOS droplet while I was waiting to hear from support.  This is the post I followed to do it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5

Comment: I followed this totorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean#configuration-details
But cannot find the line to set APP_ROOT in the unicorn.service file as specified in the tutorial. Is it now to find anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I found it here:

```
/var/lib/digitalocean/unicorn.sh
```